# Get Object if Many to Many field contains a certain Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to implement a friend system in django and am having trouble verifying when two users are already friends (in order to prevent double requesting)

The system works by having each user separately map to the same friend object to signify friendship.

Consider the following code

### models.py

```py
class Friendship(models.Model): 
    # some other stuff ... 

class FriendshipMapping(models.Model): 
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('User',related_name="friendship_mappings",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    friendship_id = models.ForeignKey('Friendship',related_name="mapped_by",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # some other stuff ...

class User(AbstractUser): 
    friendships = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Friendship', 
        through='FriendshipMapping', 
        symmetrical=True, 
        through_fields=('user_id','friendship_id'), 
        related_name='joined_users', 
    )
    # some other stuff ...
```

Now say I have 2 `User` objects and I would like to figure out if a friendship object is pointed to by both of them without getting one of their full friendship set and iterating through it. I have tried the following

```py
existing_friendship = user1.friendships.get(joined_users__in=user2)
```

but it returns empty even when I know that there is a friendship that they both point to.

There is very little documentation on this type of lookup and I'm not sure if my syntax is valid or what `__in` is really doing in the first place. Is something like this even possible in django?

Would love some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query for `Friendship`s that are associated with both users in `FriendshipMapping` like thiss:

```
existing_friendships = (Friendship.objects
    .filter(mapped_by__user_id=user1)
    .filter(mapped_by__user_id=user2)
)
```